# Flutter 'get method was call on nul' Error

Tags: flutter, dart, http, dart-null-safety

I was doing news app on Flutter and I was working with non-null safety because I was doing the older project.But then I started getting errors and I change my version to make the app with null-safety. Anyways, I changed the version re-edit the code I was thinking that I did great work but suddenly I'm getting this error right now. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your import do like below.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

call your response like below...

```
http.Response response = await http.get(
      endPointUrl,
    );
```

As of my knowledge we cant declare http with var....thats why its shows error...above code will work